# Couchbase plugin for ElasticSearch deprecated?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, couchbase

I was reading https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating-rivers which stats that ES rivers (plugin) are getting deprecated. i.e. any plugin directly integrated with ElasticSearch server will no longer work beyond ES 3.x onwards.

Couchbase plugin is one of those kind.

I searched all the documents of couchbase plugin at http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/connectors/elasticsearch-2.1/elastic-intro.html but could not find if they are using deprecated way or not?

Does anyone know? Should we keep using couchbase plugin or should start planning to write data directly to ES using our application.

We have couchbase data getting replicated to ES using couchbase plugin and XDCR.

Comment: The Couchbase plugin only supports ES 1.3.0 - 1.7.x http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/connectors/elasticsearch-2.1/release-notes.html

Comment: @cricket_007 true for now. But while evaluating path forward for our application, we need to know the options. If couchbase plugin does not advance it's capability with newer version of ES then it is dead anyway.

Comment: As far as I know, Couchbase seems focused on their own full-text search solution. I'm sure the ES 5.x release broke more than just the Couchbase connector.

Comment: @cricket_007 that is incorrect. it fully support 2.x and 5.x https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase

Comment: @RoiKatz 1) This is what I don't understand - the official site is not kept up to date in some regards 2) I hesitate to read "fully supported" when it says "alpha".

Comment: @cricket_007 1) Don't know why, you are right the site has to be more up to date.. 2) only 5.x is on alpha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the Couchbase ES transport plugin. As Roi mention in his answer, the plugin doesn't use rivers, so it won't be deprecated. It currently supports any version of ES from 1.3 to 2.x, and I'm working on adding support for 5.x. It's taking a bit longer, because ES 5.x broke some configuration sharing features in unexpected ways.

I'd suggest always looking at our github repo for the latest plugin releases:
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase

Answer (score 3):

The Couchbase plugin is not using Rivers, there is another River plugin which is not longer valid.
take a look here: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase